# Code coverage report for Mono

Tags: c#, mono, nunit, code-coverage

Is there an open-source tool that generates HTML-based reports for unit test code coverage for Mono/C# projects running on Linux or Mac OS X on the same quality level that other platforms do (Node.js and Ruby have all excelent code coverage reporting tools)?

All the tools out there that I could find (like Opencover, NCover, etc) look outdated/obsolete or low quality.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked MonoCov ([project page](http://www.mono-project.com/Code_Coverage) and [GitHub](https://github.com/mono/monocov))?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new project from one of the mono developers: https://github.com/inorton/XR.Baboon
It appears to be still in heavy development, but it works for me.